# Call/link a C++ source in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, user-interface, math, linker, wxwidgets

I don't know if it is possible to make my UI display results of calculations made with cpp code in ListBox or wxPanel.

Can someone assist me on this confusion?

Do I have to:

1. write the formulas in wxWidgets(if is possible) or
2. there is a way to make my UI communicate with the C++ source code?

I am prefer the 2nd option.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You're talking about wxWidgets as if it _ISN'T_ a C++ library. But it _IS_.

Comment: Why do you thing wxWidgets is not  a `c++` library? ***I could not find any info in the documents on this issue*** That is because its a non issue. Whoever led you to believe it was an issue is wrong.

Comment: @ManCed, you have multiple options depending what you want to achieve and how big/long the calculation takes place. Are you saying that your calculation is written in C++ and you just want to display the results? Did you look at the samples directory of wxWidgets distribution? I suggest you do, even if you are not working with windows.

Comment: Thanks Igor. I will check. The calculations are actually big  I am trying to make a metallurgical accounting desktop app.@drescherjm what I meant is that I did not see any tutorials on calculations using wxwidgets.

Comment: What I want here is the user to give inputs, which will be a lot of numbers...Then those numbers processed and calculations done and then results displayed on the UI, I need to marry my C++ file that has formulas with the UI.

Comment: @ManCed, understood. I hope you already have a design for you input panel. Take a look at the widgets sample in the same directory. Basically what you will do is design the input form and then click ok. At that time you program will read the file and perform you calculations. And then will give you the result that you can present back to the user. But you should start with designing input form. I presume you are on Windows? What compiler/IDE will you use?

Comment: I am using Code Blocks with GCC compiler. Yes that is actually what I want to achieve in your description. Now the challenge is I am new to wxwidgets and only know its basics. But thanks I will check the site. Are there any books you can recommend on these topic?

Comment: @ManCal, there is a book. It was written a long time ago. But conceptually it is still good. However the best way to learn is to build the and run the samples and then look at their code to see what is happenning.

Comment: Noted. I will keep you updated on the progress.